# How to call a JavaScript function inside the dynamically generated HTML using document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am generating dynamic HTML using JavaScript's getElementById and in that HTML I have some functions call on the onclick event and they are not working. Below is my code snippet.

**Dynamic HTML**

```
function appendAbc() {
        document.getElementById('showAbc').innerHTML = `
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="mpa-bg-text">Backgrounds</label><a class="pl-2 text-primary" id="random"
                        onclick="set_bg_dropdown()" style="cursor:pointer"><i
                            class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a><label class="text-danger pl-2"
                        style="font-size:11px">( Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5" id="mpa-no-of-bg-div">
                    <select class="form-control" id="mpa-no-of-bg" name="total-bgs"
                        onchange="set_bg_div()">

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mt-4" id="mpa-bg-div">

                </div>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group row" id="mpa-preview-div" style="display: block">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded shadow" onclick="preview()" id="mpa-preview-button"
                    name="preview">Preview</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded shadow" id="mpa-upload-button">
                    Upload
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>`};
```

I am new to Js, pls help me how can I call those functions after generating the HTML using Js.

Comment: So `preview()` inside `onclick` is defined outside the dynamic HTML? Is there an error in your browser console?

Comment: yes it is defined outside the dynamic HTML, inside the <script> tag. No I do not have any errors on console. 

edit: none of the event functions are working, onclick, onchange etc

Comment: I mean an error in console when you click the `a` element to which `onclick` is assigned with `preview()`.

Comment: yes I got it, but my console in totally empty. None of JavaScript is working when I dynamically generated the HTML, before that it was working fine but my frontend needs dynamic HTML for some reasons, so I have no other options.

edit: I have fixed this issue

Comment: If you fixed it, post the fix as answer to your question.

Comment: although onchange that is assigned with set_bg_div() (a jquery function) is still not working

Comment: Hmm, which functions work and which doesn't? Maybe it's called but doesn't work because it has a bug in its code, perhaps?

Comment: no, "set_bg_dropdown()" is basically a Js function to render out dynamic HTML for a select dropdown. It is working perfectly fine if I use my HTML as static instead of getting from Js

Comment: You mean `set_bg_div`? `preview` works right?

Comment: yes ```preview``` works fine now... having issues with ```set_bg_div``` ...it is also a Js function

Comment: So let's ask ourselves: why `preview` works while `set_bg_div` doesn't? It means that it's not about dynamic vs static HTML, maybe it's about where is the HTML put, for example.

Comment: hmm, I'll have a look at it again. Thanks!

Comment: one thing, if we create dynamic HTML using getElementById...all the functions assigned to events should work fine, right?

Comment: As long as those functions are defined then yes, it's when having a script tag inside the dynamic HTML like `document.getElementById('something').innerHTML += \`<script> console.log('hello');</script>\`` that won't execute like that (it will need special handling).

Answer (score 0):

I cut and paste the snippet into an HTML wrapper and here is the working code. BTW, personally I'd avoid using backtick just for the purpose of multiple lines assignment, since the backtick is typically used for ${} evaluation. So I'd say use it with caution.

You may throw in more details to go further.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>BootStrap Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>BS Events</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="appendXyz()"> ShowABC </button>

<div id='showAbc'>Place Holder</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

function set_bg_dropdown() {
  alert("set_bg_dropdown");
}

function set_bg_div() {
  alert("set_bg_div");
}

function preview() {
  alert("preview");
}

function appendXyz() {
  document.getElementById('showAbc').innerHTML =`
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <label for="mpa-bg-text">Backgrounds</label><a class="pl-2 text-primary" id="random"
             onclick="set_bg_dropdown()" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a><label class="text-danger pl-2"
               style="font-size:11px">( Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.)</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5" id="mpa-no-of-bg-div">
                    <select class="form-control" id="mpa-no-of-bg" name="total-bgs" onchange="set_bg_div()">
                    <option selected>Click here to select the menu</option>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 mt-4" id="mpa-bg-div">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row" id="mpa-preview-div" style="display: block">
      <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded shadow" onclick="preview()" id="mpa-preview-button"
                    name="preview">Preview</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded shadow" id="mpa-upload-button">
                    Upload
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
`;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```